# add row number based on given column value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to add numbers to my rows based on the product value:

Lets say Ive got table:

```
ProductId Value
001 10
002 30
003 20
```

then when I order it by Value asc I would get:

```
ProductId Value
001 10
003 20
004 30
```

Now I want to add new column called Position and the result would be like this:

```
ProductId Value Position
001 10 1
002 30 3
003 20 2
```

Thanks for any help how can I do this.

My database serrver is sql server 2008R2

Comment: Your example still isnt congruent.  You've now added a ProductId of 004 that doesnt fit in the previous or subsequent values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number`

```
WITH T 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER(ORDER BY ProductId) AS P 
         FROM   tablename) 
UPDATE T 
SET    Position = P
```

Of course keeping this in synch following changes in the data may be hassle than it's worth if this is not a one off requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out the answer:
First add column: 'Position' and then:

```
Update A
SET A.Position = B.Position
from [Product] A join (
SELECT [ProductId]
      ,[Value]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Value) as Position
  FROM Product)  B
  ON A.ProductId= B.ProductId
```

Comment: You don't need the join.